# animateWithDuration not recognised?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to do a cross dissolve on three UILabels (display1, display2, display3), by using a block animation to fade out, change text and then fade them in one at a time. The code I'm using is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay: 1.0
    animations:^{
        display1.alpha = 0.0;
        display2.alpha = 0.0;
        display3.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    completion:^{
        [display1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[engine getstring]]];
        [display2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[engine getstring]]];
        [display3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[engine getstring]]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0
            animations:^{
                display1.alpha = 1.0;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0
                    animations:^{
                        display2.alpha = 1.0;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                            delay:1.0
                            animations:^{
                                display3.alpha = 1.0;
                            } completion:nil];
                    } completion:nil];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Method '+animateWithDuration:delay:animations:completion:' not found*
```

and

```
'UIView' may not respond to method '+animateWithDuration:delay:animations:completion:'
```

I'm using Xcode 4.0 with an iOS Build Target of 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

instead. Note the `options:` in the middle.

Comment: Thanks. You're absolutely right. Fat finger moment, and not seeing what was(n't) there!

Comment: @John: Glad you got it sorted out. If this works for you, please click the little check mark to "accept" it as the correct answer. Best of luck with your app.